# I would like to find the Hours between two date time and need to exclude weekend hours( saturday & sunday) without function and procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i need to find the processing hours for below data between start and end date and i need to exclude saturday and sunday in between those dates

Sample data

[image]

Query i use for finding hours but not able to find the weekend calculation

```
SELECT
    name,
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    to_char(StartDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')                 StartDate,
    to_char(EndDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')                EndDate,
    to_char(datediff('hh', StartDate, EndDate), 'fm9999999.90') hours
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    
     StartDate > '01/01/2022'
    AND EndDate < '08/08/2022'
 
ORDER BY
   StartDate DESC;
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `datediff` function. What is your actual DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

Although there us no datediff command for Oracle here is an implementation, which can be used.

```
create or replace function datediff( p_what in varchar2,                                        p_d1   in date,                                        p_d2   in date ) return number
    as
        l_result    number;
    begin
        select (p_d2-p_d1) *
              decode( upper(p_what),
                       'SS', 24*60*60, 'MI', 24*60, 'HH', 24, NULL )
        into l_result from dual;
 
      return l_result;
   end;
/

 select datediff( 'ss', 
  to_date('01-AUG-2022 12:02:04', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
to_date('09-AUG-2022 18:22:34', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )) seconds FROM DUAL;

SECONDS
714029.9999999999999999999999999999999999



select datediff( 'mi', 
  to_date('01-AUG-2022 12:02:04', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
to_date('09-AUG-2022 18:22:34', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )) minutes FROM DUAL;

MINUTES
11900.5


select datediff( 'hh', 
  to_date('01-AUG-2022 12:02:04', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
to_date('09-AUG-2022 18:22:34', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )) hours FROM DUAL;

HOURS
198.341666666666666666666666666666666667


CREATE TABLE table_name (name, startdate, enddate) AS
SELECT 'DOC1', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-15 09:00:00', 
TIMESTAMP '2022-08-15 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'DOC2', TIMESTAMP'2022-08-16 09:00:00', 
TIMESTAMP '2022-08-16 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'DOC3', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-17 09:00:00', 
TIMESTAMP '2022-08-17 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'DOC4', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-18 09:00:00', 
TIMESTAMP '2022-08-18 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'DOC5', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-19 09:00:00', 
TIMESTAMP '2022-08-19 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'DOC6', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-20 09:00:00', 
TIMESTAMP '2022-08-20 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'DOC7', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-21 09:00:00', 
TIMESTAMP '2022-08-21 17:00:00' FROM DUAL; 


SELECT
    name,
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
   datediff( 'hh', startdate, enddate)
FROM
    TABLE_NAME 
WHERE startdate between to_date( '01-AUG-2022 00:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )
and to_date( '31-AUG-2022 23:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )
 AND
TO_CHAR(startdate, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN');
ORDER BY 1,2

NAME    STARTDATE   ENDDATE DATEDIFF('HH',STARTDATE,ENDDATE)
DOC1    15-AUG-22 09.00.00.000000 AM    15-AUG-22 05.00.00.000000 PM    8
DOC2    16-AUG-22 09.00.00.000000 AM    16-AUG-22 05.00.00.000000 PM    8
DOC3    17-AUG-22 09.00.00.000000 AM    17-AUG-22 05.00.00.000000 PM    8
DOC4    18-AUG-22 09.00.00.000000 AM    18-AUG-22 05.00.00.000000 PM    8
DOC5    19-AUG-22 09.00.00.000000 AM    19-AUG-22 05.00.00.000000 PM
```